# Unity Scroll View Not Allowing Me to add animations to elements inside

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity and I have a horizontal scroll view which I have 5 cards inside of it but I want to be able to add individual animations to each one of these cards. But there is an issue when I want to add an animation I cannot access any of the properties of the object to add an animation like position, scale, rotation and so on. If anyone could help that would be great

Answer (score 0):

If you have parent object of your content that has layout (horizontal/vertical) component then it is correct behaviour. It takes control over it's child RectTransforms. To help any further I need more context (more about UI setup).

Comment: I have a scroll view then inside that element I have a viewport then I have a content box and inside that there is all my cards